# How do I look up a value in a hash based on an array of keys?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, key

With Ruby (2.4), I want to extend the core hash functionality to search for keys based on an array and return the value from the first element that can be found from that array.  I have this in my lib/core_ext/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb file ...

```
class CaseInsensitiveHash < HashWithIndifferentAccess
  # This method shouldn't need an override, but my tests say otherwise.
  def [](key)
    if key.kind_of?(Array)
      find_by_arr(arr)
    else
      super convert_key(key)
    end
  end

  protected

  def convert_key(key)
    key.respond_to?(:downcase) ? key.downcase : key
  end

  def find_by_arr(arr)
    arr.inject(self){|h, k| h.to_h[k]}
  end

end
```

However, it is not working as expected. In my code below, the search 'h[["a", "b"]]' should produce "1", because the first element, "a", is a key in my hash.

```
2.4.0 :001 > h = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2}
 => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
2.4.0 :002 > h["a"]
 => 1
2.4.0 :003 > h[["a", "b"]]
 => nil
```

How do I modify my code so that I can pass in an array as a key to a hash and it will start searching for values iteratively by each element in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it, but the problem is that `h = { ... }` creates a plain-old Hash, not the kind you've added these methods to.

The first fix is to do this:

```
h = CaseInsensitiveHash["a" => 1, "b" => 2]
```

Then you get the right type of object and your method actually runs.

There's a typo in your `[]` method which can be corrected:

```
def [](key)
  case key
  when Array
    find_by_arr(key)
  else
    super convert_key(key)
  end
end
```

Your reference to `arr` doesn't work because that's not defined.

The `find_by_arr` method also returns the last match, not the first. This can be fixed:

```
def find_by_arr(arr)
  self[arr.first { |key| self[key] }]
end
```